# OpenCart не выполняет скрипт

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, opencart

Есть скрипт, который на локальной машине работает корректно, но при установке его на сервер в файл product.tpl (cms OpenCart)ничего не происходит. Скрипт берет цену из таблицы с учетом id товара. Ошибок код никаких не выводит. Спасибо за помощь.

```html
  <?php
    $host = 'хост';
    $db   = 'имя бд';
    $user = 'юзер нейм';
    $pass = 'пароль';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT price FROM oc_product WHERE product_id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
     foreach ($stmt as $row)
     {
      echo 'price '.$row['price'] . "\n";
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: Цикл while() по http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: не помогло. Попробовал:      while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) !== false),  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)), while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ALL)). Есть еще предложения?

Comment: `var_dump($stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]));` что выведет, если поставить вместо `$stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);`?

Comment: @visman при цикле while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) выводит true

Comment: Тогда перед циклом сделайте `var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());` и вероятнее всего увидите пустой массив :)

Comment: @Visman  да, но как мне это может помочь? о_О

Comment: Например, `$_GET['id']` у вас содержит не то, что ожидалось. Или не к той базе подключились ;)

Comment: @Visman,  спасибо Вам, все верно, get id возвращал ничего) При таком адресе  "product&product_id=58" нужно было писать $_GET['product_id']. Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_GET['id'] ничего не вызывало, правильно  $_GET['product_id']

Comment: немного не в тему: в opencart  хорошая модель для работы с бд., реализованы и mysqli и pdo.  зачем описываете новое подключение? ваш сайт от этого не выиграет. И очень нехорошо, что это всё ещё и в tpl файле. с уважением.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да, согласен с Вами по поводу базовых функций платформы. Я переписал запрос. Тот пример что в ТС делался на локальной машине, которая не имела cms, но имела выгруженную бд из опенкарт. Спасибо за рекомендации)